# Understanding json_agg performance in Postgres 9.5

Tags: performance, postgresql

I'm trying to understand substantial speed differences I'm seeing between similar DB queries, and I was hoping for some insight on why certain aggregations are so much slower than others.

I noticed some speed issues with a simple document retrieval query, and a substantial part of it appears to be the `json_agg` function:

```
SELECT containers.*, json_agg(content_items.*) as items FROM containers
INNER JOIN content_items ON containers.id = content_items.container_id 
GROUP BY containers.id 
ORDER BY containers.order_date DESC, containers.id DESC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

Shows a total query time of around 500ms, with over 400ms of that spent in the aggregation step:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=11921.58..12607.34 rows=17540 width=1553) (actual time=78.818..484.071 rows=17455 loops=1)
```

Simply switching `json_agg` to `array_agg` brings the total time down into the 150ms range, although about half of the time is still spent aggregating:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=11921.58..12607.34 rows=17540 width=1553) (actual time=81.975..147.207 rows=17455 loops=1)
```

Performing the query without grouping or aggregation brings the total time down to 25ms, although that would return a variable number of `containers` depending on how many `content_items` were in each.

Is there a reason for the `json_agg` to impose such a penalty? Is there a performant way to retrieve a set number of `container` rows, alongside all of their `content_items`, and simply aggregate in the application layer?

Answer (score 0):

You could do two queries: The first would get the appropriate containers, ordered and limited to 25. The second would get the content_items using a where-in clause. The application could then filter and map the contents into the appropriate containers.